# How to conditionally grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a web page that I have curled, and I choose a swatch of markup language that is `$num` of lines big (`$num` is a slight over estimate) by:

```
grep -A $num markerA
```

...then tighten up that swatch for a good data parser by piping into:

```
grep -B $num markerB
```

Let's pretend the page looks like:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
data
markerA
DATA
DATA
DATA
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
DATA
DATA
markerB
```

The data I want is capitalized. This seems to work well, and I am at odds with getting Perl tables or Perl html::parser working at this junction.

My issue comes about when the web page throws some extra data into it making my calculation for `$num` be off so what i am curious is if the page looks somewhat like:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
data
markerA
DATA
DATA
DATA
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
DATA
DATA
markerC
data
data
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
data
markerB
```

How can I word the grep expression to look for `markerC` first and if it exists parse out the before number of lines, but if it doesnt exist look for `markerB`, and not look for both of them.

I am more than sure some expression with `&&` or `||` is what I am looking for, but to be honest that is the next level of bash understanding for me.

EDIT:  it appears that markerA appears multiple times in the output... also after marker C and before markerB

Comment: If the web page is HTML or XML, you should be using an HTML or XML parser to extract the data you want.

Comment: like i said i can not get HTML::parse to work at the given time... and would prefer the script i have written there is just this one hangup

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you might be using the wrong tool — `sed` makes it very easy.

```
sed -n '/markerA/,/marker[BC]/p'
```

If you must use `grep`, then:

```
grep -A $num markerA file | grep -B $num 'marker[BC]'
```

should do the trick.  If the alternatives are not so simple, then (with GNU `sed`):

```
sed -n -r '/markerA/,/markerB|Ctag/p'
```

or with GNU `grep`:

```
grep -A $num markerA file | grep -B $num -E 'markerB|Ctag'
```

Comment: nmind... im an idiot sometimes.. i totally get it....but still wouldnt that match all of markera- markerb including markerC etcetc as it is....  i dont want it matching both just the first one it gets

Comment: i mean doesnt sed read from right to left... so it would match the end marker first and include any ending marker and the data in between

Comment: The `sed` command will match and print the lines from the first line containing markerA up to the next line containing either markerB or markerC, but once it encounters one or the other of the end markers, it stops printing until it comes across another markerA.  The `-n` suppresses the normal printing of lines; the `p` prints the matched lines.  If you don't want the matching lines (just the DATA lines in between), you have to work a little harder, but only a little harder.  The `grep` mechanisms are less precise; personally, I'd use `sed`.

Comment: oh no thats perfect then... i was just making sure it wouldnt double book the match expression...  i will test this out and get back...obviously the script this is in is a little more complicated... and its an automated script to retrieve market prices off of an unnamed website for automated price matching in OFBiz, so anything could come up and break this thing... but i will vote if it works

Comment: for what its worth the sed command doenst work and neither does the grep command, the grep command does exactly what i said... it double books the match expression... and sed command just prints everything out

Comment: Well, I beg to differ.  Testing on Linux with your data from the question, the first `sed` script works correctly.  With the `markerC` line changed to `Ctag`, the second script also works correctly.  Which platform are you working on?  Which version of `sed` are you using?  Also, with `num=10`, the two `grep` commands both work for me, on Linux (an Ubuntu 14.04 derivative).   (Which version of `grep` are you using?)  Also, when you say "doesn't work", in what way do the commands not work?  No output at all?  Wrong output?  Too little data? Too much?  Double printed?

Comment: and i figured out why... markerA appears multiple times in the output.. please see the edit, so is there a way that this can only be executed once?

Comment: OK; so in fact, the code does work OK?  If you decide you only want the first block of data in the file, then you need to upgrade the `sed` script along the lines of: `sed -n '/markerA/,/marker[BC]/{p; /marker[BC]/q; }'` (create a block of commands; print the lines; if the line is the end line, quit).

Comment: i love the learning process of bash... it is very amazing... apparently all i need is the -m 1 arguement and the above method works great with grep... sed i havent figured out yet

Comment: ok i get what you wrote and it works.great, and to be totally honest i already had an or statement in the regexp for the grep -B command before even posting here, but i failed to notice that markerA repeats itself